# Историю элемента input не нужно отображать

Tags: html

Как запретить отображение истории элемента input при вводе текста? Она только мешает...

Answer (score 8):

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
```

http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/autocomplete